# Any ideas on why a template/widget wouldn't update on the development site? It works on my local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitefinity

I have a widget and a page layout that are not working as they should on the development server.  The development server is hosted on Azure.   On my local machine, it is working properly.  I'm at a lost on what the issue is.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to check/test?  Is there any way I could test/debug this better?

Comment: What specifically isn't working? ...I don't suppose there's a public link to look at things?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an internal application.  I've inherited this project from a previous company.  The code is retrieving code from the Model.Items and outputting them on the page.  Do you have any suggestions on how to debug or get more details as to why this isn't working?

Comment: most probably there is a null reference exception somewhere, but hard to tell without any details

Comment: I discovered that the widget I'm working on is very similar to this code sample: https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.DynamicContent/WidgetTemplates/ContainerTemplates/ListTemplateContainer.cshtml What would be a good way to debug/test this?

Comment: Could be anything. Is the dev server on Azure a virtual machine? or is it a web app?

Comment: I did some more testing and I noticed that it's only the first widget is firing when placed in the placeholder.  Additional widgets will not fire/run.  Is there an issue with the template or widget that would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Sitefinity to support and they pointed me in the right direction.  I inadvertently had the wrong namespace in the widget.  Unfortunately, the widget didn't display an error message.  I had to go to the log files to find the issue.